# What does the "u-" prefix mean in Medium.com's CSS class names?

Tags: css

I was inspecting [Medium.com](https://medium.com) and saw class names like `u-marginAuto`, `u-clearfix`, and `u-baseColor`.

```
<div class="list u-baseColor u-marginAuto u-clearfix">
    ...
</div>
```

What does the "u-" prefix mean and what methodology uses this technique?

Comment: By intuition I'm thinking it means 'universal' &mdash; as in 'universally applicable to any element'.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a personal / company-wise choice regarding readability and consistency

They wrote [this ***awesome*** article](https://medium.com/@fat/mediums-css-is-actually-pretty-fucking-good-b8e2a6c78b06#.c4h6u8t4v) about it:

> - .js- prefixed class names for elements being relied upon for javascript selectors
> - **.u- prefixed class name for single purpose utility classes like .u-underline, .u-capitalize, etc.**
> - Introduction of meaningful hypens and camelCase — to underscore the separation between component, descendant components, and modifiers
> - .is- prefixed classes for stateful classes (often toggled by js) like .is-disabled
> - New CSS variable semantics: [property]-[value]--[component]
> - Mixins reduced to polyfills only and prefixed with .m-

(emphasis mine)